# Dual boot problem Windows 8 & Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

new to Linux and am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I'm having problems with the boot manager, as the GRUB2 menu is not allowing me to launch Windows 8. The Windows 8 Launcher option gives me this message every time I use it:

```
error: unknown command 'drivemap'.
error: invalid EFI file path.

Press any key to continue...
```

I have run boot-repair and that got the Ubuntu launcher working, but the problem with the Windows launcher in GRUB stays persistent.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/7091293

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu on Legacy Mode (Non-UEFI)?

Please read http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported

Answer (score 1):

Your install is UEFI.

It looks like you ran the 'buggy' UEFI in Boot-Repair. That is only required if you have a system that only boots Windows from UEFI menu.

To undo & to rename files to their original names, you just need to tick the "Restore EFI backups" option of Boot-Repair.

Also it looks like the only boot entry that will work currently is:

```
Windows UEFI bkpbootmgfw.efi
```

That is the renamed file that Boot-Repair renamed. If you undo the rename it will be without the bkp at beginning.

Boot-Repair also adds all the efi files that HP added as boot options. If you do not want those you have to edit 25_custom.

```
sudo cp -a /etc/grub.d/25_custom /etc/grub.d/bkup25_custom
gksudo gedit /etc/grub.d/25_custom
sudo update-grub
```

It also looks like os-prober is writing BIOS type entries that will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
apt-get install os-prober && os-prober
```